# Find Root Parent of self join table Column used as Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a `Locations` table which is self joined making hierarchy of administrative division. Like `State`, `County`, `Town` etc. 
`LocationId` is `PK` of this `table` and it is used as `Foreign key` in `joining table`. Joining table has `ProjectId` and `LocationsId`, Project can be at any level of location so joining table can have county, town etc. I want to find out `root-parent(State)` of location used as FK.
Please use following `sql` as sample.(copy/paste in management studio)

```
DECLARE @Locations TABLE (LocationId INT, LocationName VARCHAR(30), ParentId INT, LocLevel INT)
INSERT INTO @Locations 
Values(1, 'State1', NULL, 1), 
(2, 'State1-County1', 1, 2),
(3, 'State1-County1-Town1', 2, 3),
(4, 'State1-County1-Town1-Muncip-1', 3, 4),
(5, 'State1-County2', 1, 2),
(6, 'State1-County2-Town1', 5, 3),
(7, 'State1-County2-Town1-Muncip-1', 6, 4),
(8, 'State2', NULL, 1), 
(9, 'State2-County1', 8, 2),
(10, 'State2-County1-Town1', 9, 3),
(11, 'State2-County1-Town1-Muncip-1', 10, 4)

DECLARE @ProjectLocations TABLE (ProjectLocationId INT, ProjectId INT, LocationId INT)
INSERT INTO @ProjectLocations
VALUES(1, 1, 2),
(2, 1, 3),
(3, 1, 4),
(4, 1, 11),
(5, 2, 3),
(6, 2, 11),
(7, 3, 10),
(8, 4, 11),
(9, 5, 9)

SELECT * FROM @Locations
SELECT * FROM @ProjectLocations
```

This should be out put

```
DECLARE @FirstOutput TABLE (ProjectLocationId INT, ProjectId INT, LocationId INT, RootParentId INT)
SELECT * FROM @FirstOutput
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following will work for you:

(I've changed all the @ tables to # tables, just for convenience)

```
WITH LocationHierachy (LocationId, ParentId)
AS
(
--Anchor
    SELECT  L.LocationId, ISNULL(L.ParentId, L.LocationId)
    FROM    #Locations L
    UNION ALL
--Recurse
    SELECT  H.LocationId, L.ParentId
    FROM    LocationHierachy H
    JOIN    #Locations L
            ON  L.LocationId = H.ParentId
)
SELECT  PL.ProjectLocationId, 
        PL.ProjectId, 
        PL.LocationId, 
        H.ParentId as RootParentId
FROM    #ProjectLocations PL
JOIN    LocationHierachy H
        ON  PL.LocationId = H.LocationId
JOIN    #Locations L
        ON  H.ParentId = L.LocationId
WHERE   L.ParentId IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive query, implemented in SQL Server with Common Table Expressions. This is an example:

```
WITH FirstOutput (ProjectLocationId,ProjectId,LocationId,RootParentId) AS
(
  SELECT
        PL.ProjectLocationId,PL.ProjectId,L.LocationId,L.LocationId
  FROM
        ProjectLocations PL
  INNER JOIN
        Locations L ON PL.LocationId=L.LocationId
  WHERE 
        L.ParentId IS NULL
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT
  PL.ProjectLocationId,PL.ProjectId,L.LocationId,F.RootParentId
  FROM
        ProjectLocations PL
  INNER JOIN
        Locations L ON PL.LocationId=L.LocationId
  INNER JOIN
        FirstOutput F ON L.ParentId=F.LocationId
 )
 SELECT * FROM FirstOutput
```

Comment: I didn't test it, it's just an example of the SQL Server feature you need to use, try searching Google for `SQL Server Common Table Expression`, you'll find plenty of examples.